# Is there any method to update NetSuite Journal Entry General Ledger Impact

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

[image]

Is there any settings for NetSuite GL Impact Credit/Debit Amount sourced from another Column?
Or We can Update Journal Entry record GL Impact by deploy one SuiteGL-Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little general which means the answer will also be...

It sounds like a a GL Plug in is what you want. It runs every time a transaction is saved. It dose NOT give you the ability to change the original lines that are created. What it dose is give you the ability to create more lines to reallocate the money so you could debit the credited account and then credit a new account.

You will need to enable the plugin before using it.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_3989534344.html

If you decide to go this route and have a more specific question please ask.